# Make Uiscrollview to move to selected region

Tags: ios

Hi I've struck with simple problem that I've added a uiscollview to view and added buttons to it dynamically from an array and I'm removing them from superview and again adding them to view before loding as in code

```
- (void)loadGroups {

    if(scroll!=nil){
        if([scroll isDescendantOfView:self.view]){

            [scroll removeFromSuperview];

        }
    }
     NSUInteger n=[self.resultSet.dataObjectList count];
    scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];
    scroll.delegate=self;
    scroll.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, (height+25));
    [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake((width-30)*n, height+25)];
    [scroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:NO];
    scroll.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    //scroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GP-BG.png"]];
    [scroll setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
    scroll.indicatorStyle=UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    scroll.bounces=NO;
    scroll.scrollEnabled=YES;
    scroll.pagingEnabled=NO;
    scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        MODELRoom *room = [self.resultSet.dataObjectList objectAtIndex:i];
        CGRect rectForTitleButton = CGRectMake(i*(width-30), 0, width-30, height+25);
        int buttonTag =10000+i;
        UIButton *titleButton = [self getButton:room tag:buttonTag ];
        titleButton.tag=buttonTag;
        [titleButton setFrame:rectForTitleButton];
        titleButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [scroll addSubview:titleButton];

        CGRect rectForLabel = CGRectMake(i*(width-30), padding-5, width-35, height-20);
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]init ];
        label.frame=rectForLabel;
        MODELRoom *room1 = [self.resultSet.dataObjectList objectAtIndex:i];
        label.text=(room1).name;
        label.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        label.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
        [scroll addSubview:label];


        CGRect rectForImageView = CGRectMake(27.5+(width-30)*i, padding+25, width-90, height-20);
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init ];
        imageView.frame=rectForImageView;
        imageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Group-icon.png"];
        [scroll addSubview:imageView];

    }
    [self.view addSubview:scroll];

    }
```

my problem is when I select a button after scrolling it is retunig to first button but I need to be there where I've selected the button. please help me where i'm doing wrong...

thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this one i hope this will work fine...

```
[scroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(titleButton.frame.origin.x, titleButton.frame.origin.y) animated:YES];
```

Comment: No it is getting out of contentsize

Answer (score 0):

once see this one,

every time scollview contentOffset value is (0,0) try to change the values of that then you will get your requirement,

```
[scroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x-value, y-value) animated:NO];
```

Comment: Here if I project X-value it is moving there directly not showing prevoius buttons. My need is it should remain there its self not to move or scroll.....

Comment: when this method will call?

Comment: you can set your own values because we don't know wht you want exactly means position of the scrollview.

Comment: tell me exactly wt u want?

Comment: for vertical scroll change x value and for horizantal scroll change y value in your case change x value only.

Comment: scrolling should remain at the position where I've selected the button

Comment: then give the y-position of the button to x-value of scroll contentOffset.

Comment: no sunny please check where is the mistake.... is there any mistake with contentsize.. or ...

Comment: are you adding buttons horizantally?if possible show me the images?

Comment: UIButton *button=[[[UIButton alloc] init] autorelease];
 
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    
    UIImage *buttonImageNormal;
    if(currenRoom.currentlySelected){
        buttonImageNormal=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"GP-BG-Slected Green.png"]];
        
        
    }else{
        buttonImageNormal=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"GP-BG.png"]];
    }
    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 
}

Comment: title button declaration in first code... and this is the get...node.. methid

Comment: in your case place the x-position of the button to  y-value of the scrollview ContentOffset